# Blackberry - run menu item from dialer Phone App

Tags: blackberry

I'd like to describe one trick I learned at [supportforums.blackberry.com](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board?board.id=java_dev)

There is a native dialer Phone Application in BlackBerry.

The trick is to programmatically run menu items of dialer after incoming call, call fail or any other call event.

Comment: I had to remove the images from your post because ImageShack has deleted them and replaced them with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [PhoneListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html) interface, which gives an ability to listen to the status of incoming and outgoing phone calls.

See [Listen for and handle phone events](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8540/Listen_for_phone_events_565556_11.jsp)

A quote from [supportforums.blackberry.com - Re: How to exit an Ui application (by simon_hain)](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&view=by_date_ascending&message.id=62284#M62284):

> Listeners are hard referenced by the application they are added to. Figuratively speaking, they become part of the rim application.
>
> If you add a listener to the phone application this listener is executed in the context of the phone app.
>   You can check this by using Ui.getUiEngine().getActiveScreen() in a listener method. The returned screen is the call screen of the phone application.
>
> I use this to execute commands on phone calls:
>   - on callInitiated or callConnected i store a reference to the phone screen.
>   - i call phoneScreen.getMenu(0)
>
> now i want to execute a command:
>   - i change the locale to "en"
>   - i iterate through the menu using menu.getSize() and menu.getItem(i)
>   - i check if menuItem.toString equals my command
>   - i call menuItem.run()
>   - and change the locale back (if it was changed)
>
> you can use this to:
>   mute
>   unmute
>   activate speakerphone
>   view speeddiallist
>   end the call (only prior to 4.5/4.6, not sure which one)
>   and many more. just print the available menu items :)

A sample code for this trick, on incoming call print all menu to console, on answer call mute phone on end call - unmute phone:

```
public class UseScreenMenu extends Application implements PhoneListener {
    String MENU_ITEM_MUTE = "Mute";
    String MENU_ITEM_UNMUTE = "Unmute";
    public UseScreenMenu() {
        Phone.addPhoneListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UseScreenMenu app = new UseScreenMenu();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public void callIncoming(int callId) {
        printMenu();    
    }

    public void callAnswered(int callId) {
        runMenuItem(MENU_ITEM_MUTE);
    }

    public void callEndedByUser(int callId) {
        runMenuItem(MENU_ITEM_UNMUTE);  
    }

    private void printMenu() {      
        Screen screen = Ui.getUiEngine().getActiveScreen();
        Menu menu = screen.getMenu(0);
        System.out.println("Menu of BB Dialler - Begin");
        for (int i = 0, cnt = menu.getSize(); i < cnt; i++)
            System.out.println("Menu of BB Dialler - "
                +menu.getItem(i).toString());
        System.out.println("Menu of BB Dialler - End");     
    }

    private void runMenuItem(String menuItemText) {
        Screen screen = Ui.getUiEngine().getActiveScreen();
        Menu menu = screen.getMenu(0);
        for (int i = 0, cnt = menu.getSize(); i < cnt; i++)
            if(menu.getItem(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(menuItemText))
                menu.getItem(i).run();
    }


    public void callAdded(int callId) {}
    public void callConferenceCallEstablished(int callId) {}
    public void callConnected(int callId) {}
    public void callDirectConnectConnected(int callId) {}
    public void callDirectConnectDisconnected(int callId) {}
    public void callDisconnected(int callId) {}
    public void callFailed(int callId, int reason) {}
    public void callHeld(int callId) {}
    public void callInitiated(int callid) {}
    public void callRemoved(int callId) {}
    public void callResumed(int callId) {}
    public void callWaiting(int callid) {}
    public void conferenceCallDisconnected(int callId) {}
}
```